# How to check if UDP packet received in C Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server, udp

"recvfrom()" in below sample code waits until UDP packet is received.

But I need to check whether UDP packet is available or not.
If packet is not received, then continue other tasks.
If packet is received, then receive packet and parsing.
How can I do this in Linux c program?  Please help!

```
for (;;) 
{
    printf("waiting on port %d\n", SERVICE_PORT);
    recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
    printf("received %d bytes\n", recvlen);
    if (recvlen > 0) {
        buf[recvlen] = 0;
        printf("received message: \"%s\"\n", buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use (`select`)[linux.die.net/man/2/select] function to know a something is ready to be read on a socket.

Comment: yes select worked.  thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) function to know a something is ready to be read on a socket.

```
while (1)
{
    int retval;
    fd_set rfds;
    // one second timeout
    struct timeval tv = {1,0};

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

    retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
    {
        perror("select()");
        exit(1);
    }        
    else if (retval)
    {
        printf("Data is available now.\n");      
    }
    else
    {
        // no data to read... perform other tasks
    }
}
```

Comment: yes select worked.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may wait for some particular seconds in code. If you didn't receive packet within that time then ask it to do further process. Or else check the return value of recvfrom to verify the received packet size.